# R Programming Speed

Tags: r

Is there any way to speed up the following R code with apply functions?  I have not yet been able to completely understand the implementation of apply functions, but I understand that they may help in reducing computing time from for loops.

Here is the code, thanks for your input!

```
for(i in 1:(365 + leap)){
    ## Filename
    IMS.file = paste('crb_',km,'km_v00_',year,
                     sprintf("%03d", i),'.asc.csv',sep='')

    ## The next step is to check that file exists
    if(file.exists(paste(IMS.folder,'/',IMS.file,sep=''))){

        ## Reads in file
        dat = read.table(paste(IMS.folder,'/',IMS.file,sep=''),
            sep=',')

  ## This removes all the values outside of the basin
        point.in.polygon(dat[,4],dat[,3],basin.coord[,1],basin.coord[,2])
  xy = as.logical(point.in.polygon(dat[,4],dat[,3],basin.coord[,1],basin.coord[,2]))

  ## Keeps points of interest, eliminates first 2 columns and reverses lat & lon
  dat = dat[xy,3:5]

    ## Changes 4 to snow (1) and all others to 0
        dat[,3] <- ifelse(dat[,3] == 4,1,0)

        ## Creates a new file (may need to be updated for new computers)
        newfile = paste('C:/Users/Ben/Documents/Columbia Project/',
                        'ColumbiaRiverBasin_Report/IMS',km,'SubBasins/',subbasin,
                        '/',year,'/',year,sprintf("%3d", i),'.csv',sep='')

        ## Adds the file header to the spreadsheet
        write.table(file.head,file=newfile,quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,
            col.names=FALSE)

        ## Appends file with the trimmed data
        write.table(dat,file=newfile,append=TRUE,
            quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=',')
    }
    else{
        ## Outputs missing day (1-366 )
        print(paste('Missing Day Number: ', i),quote=FALSE)
    }
}
```

Comment: probably not: (1) apply functions generally lead to at most very minor/subtle speed increases (search for & read Patrick Burns's *R Inferno*); (2) vectorization is generally what you need instead, if possible; (3) if you have to process the daily files separately you're probably screwed. The only exception is that you may be able to use *parallel* versions of `apply()` from the `parallel` package ...

Comment: PS I don't know where your bottlenecks are (most likely either `points.in.polygon` or  file I/O), but . ... is there a reason you're running `point.in.polygon(dat[,4],dat[,3],basin.coord[,1],basin.coord[,2])` once, uselessly, before running it a second time and storing the results?

Comment: Ben - thank you; I didn't even notice that and it definitely speeds it up.

Answer (score 3):

I see significant speed increases with the `data.table` [package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/), in particular `fread` is amazing, and you can select specific columns instead of reading all of them. If your files are large, this will significantly speed things up. So your read in would become:

```r
## Reads in file
## Not this: dat = read.table(paste(IMS.folder,'/',IMS.file,sep=''),
##        sep=',')

## This instead
dat <- fread("<filename>", select = <list of columns you want>)
```

Comment: Very helpful! This is awesome - I never knew about this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

read_special = function(sub_df)
  with(sub_df,
       "crb_%skm_v00%s%03d.asc.csv" %>%
         sprintf(first(km), first(year), first(day)) %>%
         paste(IMS.folder, . , sep='/') %>%
         read.table(sep = ",",
                    col.names = c(
                      "trash1",
                      "trash2",
                      "latitude",
                      "longitude",
                      "some_other_variable") )

read_special = failwith(data_frame(), read_special)

# start by building a dataframe called catalog with columns year, day, and km 
# for all the files you think you have

catalog %>%
  group_by(year, day, km) %>%
  do(read_special(.)) %>%
  select(-trash1, -trash2) %>%
  filter(point.in.polygon(longitude, latitude,
                          basin.coord$longitude, basin.coord$latitude))) %>%
  write.csv("C:/Users/Ben/Documents/Columbia Project/all_data.csv",
            row.names = FALSE)
```

Though I don't know how to do it, I agree with suggestion to use fread (or library(readr) ). A few notes: always work with column names as opposed to numbers if possible. It makes everything much clearer. failwith is a bit dangerous, because it might mask errors besides a csv not existing. Ground-truth a bit. I highly highly recommend writing out all of your data into exactly 1 csv file.